# How to select all values between 2 tables in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, join

I have the following two tables in Oracle database (read only access so I can only use select).

`Question` table:

```
N   Question ID
1   1
2   2
3   3
```

`Response` table:

```
Question ID     Response day
1               01-04-15
3               02-04-15
4               03-04-15
```

I want the output result to be:

```
Question ID  Response day
1            01-04-15
2            null
3            02-04-15
4            03-04-15
```

I m strying with the following query and I'm ony getting the question ID when there is a response. Anyone know where I'm going wrong?

```
select questionID, responseday 
from questions
join response
where question.question.ID = response.question.ID;
```

With this query I'm getting these results:

```
Question  ID    Response day
1               01-04-15
3               02-04-15
4               03-04-15
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your schema, a simple `LEFT JOIN` will be sufficient for your model.

```
SELECT     q.Question_ID, 
           r.Response_Day
FROM       Question AS "q"
           LEFT JOIN Response AS "r"
                ON r.Question_ID = q.Question_ID;
```

`JOIN` or `INNER JOIN` will **only** return the result sets from both tables where ALL attributes match. Because your `Question` record with ID of `2` does not exist in the Response table, SQL will exclude this data.

To account for `NULLs`, you have to `LEFT JOIN`, see the sqlfiddle here:
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2e998/1/0)

Also, have a look at this graphical model explaining all the `JOINs`:
[Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Answer (score 2):

One method is a full outer join:

```
select coalesce(q.questionid, r.questionid) as questionid,
       r.responseday
from questions q full outer join
     responses r
     on q.questionid = r.questionid;
```

Comment: Actually, I think a left join is sufficient.

Comment: `full outer join` may be the right answer because of the question_id 4 in response table, and the question_id 2 in question table.
The desired output includes all available data in both tables

Answer (score 0):

Use Left Join

```
select 
      q.questionid  as questionid,
      r.responseday
from 
     questions q 
left join
     responses r
on 
     q.questionid = r.questionid;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FULL outer JOIN is sufficient or the output required.

SELECT NVL(a.id,b.id),
  b.nm
FROM
  (SELECT 1 id,1 nm FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 id,2 nm FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 id,3 nm FROM dual
  )a
FULL OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT 1 id,'01-04-15' nm FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 3 id,'02-04-15' nm FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 id,'03-04-15' nm FROM dual
  )b
ON a.id = b.id;


---------------------------------OUTPUT -----------------------------------

ID  NM
1   01-04-15
3   02-04-15
4   03-04-15
2   NULL
----------------------------------OUTPUT-----------------------------------
```

Answer (score -4):

```
select questionID
,      responseday 
from   questions
join   response
   on  question.question.ID = response.question.ID;
```

Comment: what is the difference between this query and the wrong query in the question ?

Comment: @Philippe . . . You might want to explain why you accepted this answer, when it is equivalent to the answer that doesn't work in the question.

Comment: Sorry mistake on my behalf. It is a left join I need to do here and it works. Thanks for your help